# Не переведены строки на странице защищённых вопросов

Tags: дефект, локализация, 10k-tools, защищённые-вопросы

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/protected-questions

> [image: защищённые вопросы]

1. Asked on.
2. Click to sort by the question creation date.
3. Protected on.
4. Click to sort by the date the question was protected.
5. Click to sort by the number of deleted answers.
6. Click to sort by the number of answers posted during the past 30 days.
7. Click to sort by the name of the user who protected the question.
8. Click to sort by the question title.